# How do I stop FixedUpdate from making my cube fall down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make it possible for the player to carry a cube, and this is what I'm using:

```cs
    obje.transform.rotation = (playerCam.transform.rotation);
    obje.transform.position = (playerCam.transform.position + transform.forward*2f);
```

It works fine on the normal void Update code, but if I try to use FixedUpdate it does this:

https://gyazo.com/a8189722fa8f45940c628c65eac68278

I can't figure out how to fix this, and I want to use FixedUpdate because otherwise when the player walks into the cube it can visibly glitch inside the camera sometimes - which looks weird.

Comment: The video is not self-explanatory because I think it looks like a cube falling down, whilst being interactively affected by the user or a moving camera. Do you have the same effect if you run your program on a computer with a different graphic card/driver?

Comment: What is the gameobject of `transform.forward*2f` ? Shouldn't it be `playerCam.transform.forward*2f` ?